# AMT - Three whole numbers add up to 149 and multiply to give 987. What is the largest of the three number

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

So about this question I'm not too sure... Can't find out what I should start off with. If anyone can help me I'll be very greatly appreciated. The question is:

> Three whole numbers add up to 149 and multiply to give 987. What is the largest of the three numbers?

I can't find the starting point where I can start off my thinking process with.

Comment: Check with combinations $1,3,7,21,47,141,329,987<149$ to get $$1,7,141$$

Comment: The way to start is to note that there are lots of combinations that sum to $149$ but relatively few that multiply to $987$, so list the latter and see what they sum to.  Once you factor $987$ you are on your way.

Answer (score 6):

It happens that $987$ is the product of three distinct primes: $\,3\cdot7\cdot47$. If $\,a\le b\le c$, $\,abc=987\,$  and $a+b+c=149$, we know that
$$1\le a,b, c\le 147,$$ 
hence $c$ must be in $\,\{1,3, 7,21,47, 141\}$.

- If $c=141$, then $b=7, \ a=1$. Indeed $a+b+c=149$ in that case.
- If $c=47$, then $ab=21$, so that $a,b\le 21$, and $a+b+c\le89$.
- If $c\le 21$, then $a+b+c\le 63$.

Thus there is only one solution is $a=1,\ b=7,\ c=141$.

Comment: Is there a typo in the second bullet point? Shouldn't it be $ab = 21$ and $a,b \leq 21$? Anyway, this seems a bit redundant: if $c \leq 47$ then $a + b + c \leq 3\cdot47 = 141$...

Comment: Oh! Yes. Thank you for pointing the typo. It's corrected now.